# generating random variable having an exponential density function

Tags: algorithm, random, simulation, exponential-distribution

I would like to generate a random variable having an exponential density function:

f(x) = e^x / (e - 1), 0 <= x <= 1

I know I can use a uniform random number generator with using the inversion method for a simple function like (e^-x). But, I am not sure how to use them on the function given above.

Any suggestions?

Comment: question modified so that not to have an "on hold"

Answer (score 1):

Per Wolfram Alpha, the integral of that density function from `0` to `a` is `(e^a-1)/(e-1)`, which inverts to `y=log((e-1)*x+1)`. So the inverse transform method should work fine.

In the more general case where the integral doesn't pan out or the inversion doesn't pan out, stochastic sampling methods are the most widely applicable methods for sampling a random variable given its probability density. The easiest to understand and implement is Rejection Sampling. After that, you're looking at Metropolis-Hastings, which is immensely powerful but not necessarily the simplest to get your head around.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to integrate `f(x)` from `0` to `x` to determine the [cumulative distribution function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cumulative_distribution_function), call this function `U`. When you (pseudo-)randomly pick a number, put it into this function `U` and find `x` that satisfies this.

Your function appears to be simple enough that direct inversion will work. If you  have a more complicated function, you would have to use a [Newton-Raphson method](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) to solve `x` for the given `U`.